# Algebraic operations on lists elements

Tags: python, list, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

I'm trying to statistically process data using python for learning purposes.

In my problem I generate two tosses of a dice n times, where X is a random variable, defining a product of two tosses. I managed how to calculate the expectation of X, then the variance of X, but I have problems with computing the standard deviation of X.

Here is my question.
How to get a third list from two lists, based on algebraic operations on elements of these two lists with the same serial numbers? Precisely, I want to get something like this.

`x = [x0, x1, .., xi, .., xn]`

`y = [y0, y1, .., yi, .., yn]`

`z = [(x0-y0)^2, (x1-y1)^2, .., (xi-yi)^2, .., (xn-yn)^2]`

Here is my code. Maybe it's a bit bulky, but it's my first one. I receive an error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'Decimal
```

on the line

```
x_error_2 = Decimal (((x_storage) - (expectation_x))**2).quantize(Decimal('.0001'))
```

Clearly, I'm doing it wrong.

```
    n = input ("n=")
    sum_x = 0
    sum_x_2 = 0
    sum_x_error_2 = 0
    x_storage = [ ]
    expectation_x_storage = []
    from decimal import Decimal
    for i in range (0, n):
        from random import *
        x = Decimal ((randint(1, 6)*randint(1, 6))).quantize(Decimal('1'))
        x_storage.append(x)
        x_2 = Decimal (x**2).quantize(Decimal('.01'))     
        sum_x = sum_x + x
        sum_x_2 = sum_x_2 + x_2
    expectation_x = Decimal (sum_x / n).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
    expectation_x_2 = Decimal (sum_x_2 / n).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
    variance_x = Decimal ((expectation_x_2 - (expectation_x)**2)).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
    print ("E(X)=")
    print (expectation_x)
    print ("V(X)=")
    print (variance_x)
    for i in range (0, n):
        expectation_x_storage.append(expectation_x)
    print x_storage
    print expectation_x_storage
    #code is working until the next line
    for i in range (0, n):
        x_error_2 = Decimal (((x_storage) - (expectation_x))**2).quantize(Decimal('.0001'))
        sum_x_error_2 = sum_x_error_2 + x_error_2
        standard_deviation_x_2 = Decimal ((sum_x_error_2)/(n-1)).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
    print ("Sn2(X)=")
    print (standard_deviation_x_2)
```

Comment: You have `x` ang `y` now you want to calculate `z` from `x` and `y` right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks that you simply need to take i-th element of x_storage here.

```
x_error_2 = Decimal (((x_storage[i]) - (expectation_x))**2).quantize(Decimal('.0001'))
```

Also change identation of the line

```
standard_deviation_x_2 = Decimal ((sum_x_error_2)/(n-1)).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
```

To place it outside for-loop. Not sure is it worth mentioning, but in python identation is critical.

Then it should work.

Seems you're using python 2.7? I'd suggest you to not mix style you call `print` with and without parentheses. Use `print(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have two lists `x = [x1,x2,...xn]` and `y=[y1,y2,...,yn]` now `z` should be `z=[(x1-y1)^2,(x2-y2)^2,...,(xn-yn)^2]`

You can do it this way:

```
>>> a=[35.5,36.6,37.7]
>>> b=[12.34,13.89,30.8]
>>> c=[(a[i]-b[i])**2 for i in range(len(a))]
>>> c
[536.3856, 515.7441, 47.61000000000003]
>>>
```

If you to round those digits you can use `round` function

```
>>> c=[round((a[i]-b[i])**2,3) for i in range(len(a))]
>>> c
[536.386, 515.744, 47.61]
>>>
```

`round(x,y)` is round number x to y decimal digits